# Sweet Tooth: Healthier to brush before/after eating sweets? Fluoride protection effective if used right before?

Tags: time-of-day, brushing-teeth, toothpaste, fluoride, sweeteners

What is the **optimal time-of-day** (if one is to live a little and eat a sweet treat every now and then) for **consuming a sugary goodie?**

***Before or after brushing teeth?***

**After:** I assume everyone one would say after brushing so you can brush all the sugar out of your teeth so it doesnt sit there all day and rot your teeth out, right? I think this too.

**Before:** But I also hear brushing right after eating is bad for your enamel because when you eat -- your enamel is soft and you end up being rough on your enamel if you brush right afterwards.

PLUS, is fluoride more protective right afterwards? If I use a fluoride-based toothpaste right before eating a treat is it more effective in protecting my teeth from the sugar rather than adding that layer of protection on after the threat of sugar enters my mouth?